# Force warning from an SSIS Data Flow task

Tags: ssis

Is it possible to force displaying a custom warning from within a Data Flow task on certain condition? 
Example: in my data flow I populate a table from a flat file. At the end I would like to display a warning message for the Data Flow task if the table has less than 10 records.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136054.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Control Flow                                Data Flow

--------------------
|     Data Flow    |                               [Source]
--------------------                                   |
   ||          ||                                      |
(RC > 10)  (RC <= 10)                        [Row Count to RC var]
   ||          ||                                      |
---------    -----------                               |
| Email |    |  Script | FiresWarning            [Destination]
---------    -----------
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can simply use a script task and count the lines and compare them.
   Go accordingly.
2. Load the package in a console application. if project run successfully then check the no. of record and display message accordinglly.
   You can a lso send email using config file.

Let me know if you want to follow any of this and need more detailed help.
i have done this in my package

Answer (score 0):

You can fire errors and warnings within a Data Flow Task with a [Script Component](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2011/02/script-task-and-component-logging.html), but it's much easier to use the Row Count Transformation to count the records and then use the variable containing the row count in an expression in the Control Flow.

Answer (score 0):

You can log messages using a [Script Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/script-task?view=sql-server-ver16).

I created a script task which logged a  `FireInformation` event.

[image]

The event was logged in the Progress portion of SSIS.

[image]

See [script component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-scripting/task/raising-events-in-the-script-task?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16#events-example) for more details.